# How to use iText to add a watermark using an embedded font

Tags: java, fonts, itext

I've several pdf/a documents with some embedded fonts, now I've to post-process these documents using iText to add a watermark.

I know that it's possible to embed a font with iText:

```
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
```

but I would like to use a font that is already embedded in the document to add the textual watermark (something like "SAMPLE COPY").

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

What you want is a `DocumentFont`.  You cannot create them directly, the constructor is package private, but `BaseFont.createFont(PRIndirectReference)` will do the trick.

So you just need to get a `PRIndirectReference` to the font you want.  "PR"s come from a PdfReader.  There are two ways to find the font you're looking for and get a reference to it:

1) Enumerate every object in the PdfReader, filtering out everything that's not a `PRStream`, from there dropping everything that's not a `/Type /Font`, and looking for a font with the correct name.

```
public PRIndirectReference findNamedFont( PdfReader myReader, String desiredFontName) {
  int objNum = 0;
  PdfObject curObj;
  do {
    //The "Release" version doesn't keep a reference 
    //to the object so it can be GC'd later.  Quite Handy 
    //when dealing with Really Big PDFs.
    curObj = myReader.getPdfObjectRelease( objNum++ );
    if (curObj instanceof PRStream) {
      PRStream stream = (PRStream)curObj;
      PdfName type = stream.getAsName(PdfName.TYPE);
      if (PdfName.FONT.equals(type)) {
        PdfString fontName = stream.getAsString(PdfName.BASEFONT);
        if (desiredFontName.equals(fontName.toString())) {
          return curObj.getIndRef();
        }
      }
    }
  } while (curObj != null);
return null;
}
```

2) Examine your pages' resource dictionaries `/Font <<>>` dicts, looking for a font with the correct name.  Keep in mind that XObject Form resources have resources of their own you'll have to check to:

```
public PRIndirectReference findFontInPage(PdfReader reader, String desiredName, int i) {

  PdfDictionary page = reader.getPageN(i); 
  return findFontInResources(page.getAsDict(PdfName.RESOURCES), desiredName);
}   

public PRIndirectReference findFontInResources(PdfDictionary resources, String desiredName) {
  if (resources != null) {
    PdfDictionary fonts = resources.getAsDict(PdfName.FONTS);
    if (fonts != null) {
      for (PdfName curFontName : fonts.keySet()) {
        PRStream curFont (PRStream)= fonts.getAsStream(curFontName);
        if (desiredName.equals(curFont.getAsString(PdfName.BASEFONT).toString()) {
          return (PRIndirectReference) curFont.getIndirectReference();
        }
      }
    }
    PdfDictionary xobjs = resources.getAsDict(PdfName.XOBJECTS);
    if (xobjs != null) {
      for (PdfName curXObjName : xobjs.keySet()) {
        PRStream curXObj = (PRStream)xobjs.getAsStream(curXObjName);
        if (curXObj != null && PdfName.FORM.equals(curXObj.getAsName(PdfName.SUBTYPE)) {
          PdfDictionary resources = curXObj.getAsDict(PdfName.RESOURCES);
          PRIndirectReference ref = findFontInResources(resources, desiredName);
          if (ref != null) {
            return ref;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Either one of those will get you the `PRIndirectReference` you're after.  Then you call `BaseFont.createFont(myPRRef)` and you'll have the `DocumentFont` you need.  The first method will find any font in the PDF, while the second will only find fonts That Are Actually Used.

Also, subsetted fonts are supposed to have a "6-random-letters-plus-sign" tag prepended to the font name.  DO NOT use a font subset.  The characters you're using may not be in the subset, leading to what I call the " arry  ole" problem.  It sounds nice and dirty, but it was really just our sales guy's name: "Harry Vole" missing the upper case letters because I'd subsetted some font I shouldn't have Many Moons Ago.

PS: never embed subsets of fonts you intend to be used in a form field.  No Bueno.

The usual "I wrote all that code in the answer box here" disclaimer applies, but I've written a LOT of this sort of code, so it just might work out of the box.  Cross your fingers.  ;)

Comment: Using iText 5.0.2 I've found this solution:
    `private PRIndirectReference getFontIndirectRef(PdfReader pdfReader, String desiredFontName) {
      PRIndirectReference font = null;
      for(Object[] obj : BaseFont.getDocumentFonts(pdfReader)){
        String fontName = (String)obj[0];
        if(fontName.equals(desiredFontName)){
            font = (PRIndirectReference)obj[1];
        }
      }
      return font;
    }

    BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(getFontIndirectRef(pdfReader, "Helvetica"));`

Answer (score 1):

An entirely different approach:  Use Line Art instead of Text.

If you create a "line art only" PdfGraphics2D object from the page's overContent, you can use an AWT font and need not worry about embedding at all.  With a relatively short string you don't have to worry about the PDF's size exploding either.

```
PdfContentByte overcontent = stamper.getOverContent(1);
Graphics2D g2d = overcontent.createGraphicsShapes(pageWid, pageHei);

drawStuffToTheGraphic(g2d);

g2d.dispose();
```

This will result in "text" that is actually line art.  It cannot be selected, searched, etc.  That could be good or bad depending on what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Using plain jPod (BSD, SourceForge) you could base on the "Watermark" example. WIth

```
PDFontTools.getFonts(doc)
```

you can enumerate the fonts and then use one of them in the "createForm" method...

Comment: Thanks for you response! Is there anything for an iText solution?

Comment: Sorry - i'm not familiar with iText.